# Multi threads in Java

Tags: java, multithreading

I have some class. For example:

```
public class Data {
    private String name;

    public Data(String url) {
        // There is download something from the Internet and set field "name".
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
}
```

In some method I need to initialize array of objects Data.

```
ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>;
for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    list.add(new Data("http://localhost/" + String.valueOf(i)));
}
```

But it is to long. I wanna do this:

```
final ArrayList<Data> list = new ArrayList<Data>;
for(int i=0; i<max; i++) {
    final int tmp = i;
    new Thread() {

        public void run() {
            list.add(new Data("http://localhost/" + String.valueOf(tmp)));
        }   

    }.start();

}
```

But the main thread ends sooner than the others and variable list is empty. What should I do? Help pls :)

UP. That is not too fast to download some data from the Internet that's why I've created several threads.

Comment: private **type** name?
public **type** Data()

Comment: `"http://localhost/" + String.valueOf(tmp)` is the same as `"http://localhost/" + tmp`

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Speed up the process? Startin new threads in every loop will only make your program slower. If you want to parallelize split the process up into intelligent junks, say of 10 elements each. You have to find a balance between the threading overhead and the work in the worker.

Comment: Also, your code won't run, there are several mistakes. As already said, you're missing type information, ListArray is also most likely ArrayList?

Comment: That's is a test code just for example. And thank you, I will do only 10 threads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of dealing with the low level details of the Thread API, you could use the java concurrent package, with an executor to handle the threads (I don't know what ListArray is but if it is not thread safe you will have issues with the solution proposed some of the other answers: adding a join will not be sufficient).

For example, a simplified example would be:

```
final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(10);
final List<Future<Data>> list = new ArrayList<Future<Data>>(max);

for (int i = 0; i < max; i++) {
    final int tmp = i;
    Callable<Data> c = new Callable<Data>() {
        @Override
        public Data call() {
            return new Data("http://localhost/" + tmp);
        }
    };
    list.add(executor.submit(c));
}

executor.shutdown();

for (Future<Data> future : list) {
    Data data = future.get(); //will block until the page has been downloaded
    //use the data
}
```

Ideally, you whould add some error handling around `future.get()`, as it will throw an `ExecutionException` if your task throws an exception, which I suppose could happen if the page is not availble for example.

Comment: Thank you very much. Your example is very useful and clever.

Answer (score 2):

**1.** When you fire the Another thread, that does the work of getting the data from net and populating the list, immediately after that use `join()` method.

**2.** `join()` method **will not let the next line to execute before the** `run()` **method of the thread on which it is called has finish().**

**3.** So your `main()` method will not be executed before the list is populated as you have used `join()` to hold the execution before the other thread is done.....

Answer (score 1):

In your main use [Thread.join](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#join%28%29) to wait for the child threads to complete

```
    Thread[] threads = new Thread[max];
    final List<Data> list = Collections.synchronizedList(new ArrayList<Data>());
    for(int i=0; i< max; i++) {
        final int tmp = i;
        Thread t = new Thread() {

            public void run() {
                list.add(new Data("http://localhost/" + String.valueOf(tmp)));
            }   

        };
        t.start();
        threads[i] = t;
    }
    for (Thread t : threads) {
        t.join();
    }
```